# what is the regular expression for this language?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, regular-expressions

the language is: L={{0,1}*|strings that contain the same number of 1's and 0's , plus there can't be three (or more) aces or zeros one after another}

for example the string cannot be: 111001 because the subword 111 contains three aces one after another (plus the number of aces is bigger than that of the zeros)

some of the accepted strings are:
01
10
0011
1100
0101
1010
0110
1001
100110
...

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 2):

Actually the language is not regular. Intersect with $\{001,011\}^*$.